# How to pull huge table (80 millions rows) from Oracle into SQL DB or SQL dump via VPN

Tags: vpn, sql, dump, database-administration

I have the task to pull a huge table from an Oracle DB into a SQL DB or SQL dump via the internet. The source DB (Oracle) is in an enterprise setting which I access via Cisco VPN (Split tunneling is not allowed).

I have tried a tool from [Intelligent Converters](http://www.convert-in.com/): Progress is very slow, which seems to be a **latency** issue (84MB in 8 hours pulled), at this rate I need more than 60 days.

The table itself is extremely simple (no no views, storage produceres, no indexes, identities etc.). Options are restricted by the VPN that does not allow split tunneling: The moment the connection stands no internet connection is present on the connected machine, I therefore need physical access.

Comment: why not create a database dump using expdp, compress it and then transfer via scp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a database dump [using expdp](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10825/dp_export.htm#i1006376), compress it using bzip2 / gzip and then transfer via scp?

I'm assuming Oracle is hosted on a *nix based OS

Comment: expdp can only be imported by another Oracle database, so you'd need to do remote oracle export, compress, scp, local oracle import, copy from local oracle to local SQL (I guess SQL Server)

Answer (score 0):

Try to experiment on Oracle TCP related parameters [Nagle algorithm (TCP_NODELAY)](http://www.miracleas.com/tools/Miracle_4_nagle.pdf).

You can also adjust sending/receiving data buffer (SDU/TDU/RECV_BUF_SIZE/SEND_BUF_SIZE) in [tnsnames.ora](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/performance.htm) or on OS level.